# ArcGIS Online Popups - Display Imagery date & time properties?

Tags: arcgis-online, image, popup

I am displaying linked images from traffic cameras in my AGO popups. The images get updated regularly. If I download an image and look at its file info it has associated date and time properties. Is there any way to show (in the popup) the date and/or time that the images were taken?

Comment: The answer is "possibly, but it depends". Remember, try to avoid simple yes/no questions on here. In order to get a relevant, useful answer, you ought to provide as much information as possible about your particular situation.
For instance, you might include a link to the traffic camera data feeds, or a screenshot of how you're using them. There probably *is* a way to do what you're asking, but it will depend a lot on the data you're working with.